# May I know what will be the correct architecture for display Crystal Report in .Net MVC?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

Let me tell you my architecture first.

There are 3 layers in our application architecture.

1. Repository layer(Database interaction layer)
2. Service layer(Business layer)
3. Presentation layer

Current implementation of our architecture is:

a. We have created models and viewmodels.

eg.

```
public class Employee
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     ..........
     ...........
     public DateTime? BirthDate {get;set;}
}
```

b. In our repository layer we are fetching data from the MS SQL database using store procedure.

c. Database returns employee table which we are converting to our model(object) and passing it through service layer.

eg: List employee = new List();

This method is in repository

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
{
    var employeeList = new List<Employee>();
    .....
    //Database interaction with Store Procedure
    .....
    //Filling employeeList object
    .....
    return employeList;
}
```

d. In Controller we are passing that model(object) to the view.

eg:

```
public ActionResult GetEmployees()
{
    var employeelist = new List<Employee>();
    .....
    .....
    return View(employeelist);
}
```

We basically display data using object in our whole applicaiton.

Now Crystal Report accepts dataset values. It does not accept null values of the properties of our object type we are passing through our architecture. Crystal report gives error like "It does not accept null values" for nullable BirthDate of Employee model.

What should be proper architecture of passing values of database to crystal report in MVC?